# How many regular users here work in IT?

Tags: discussion, users

Every day, I realize that more and more people here know a lot more about tech than I'd expect a random set of Jews to know.  It makes sense, but of the regular users, what percent work in or have worked in IT?

Comment: An easy way to do a spot-check on this would be to trawl peoples' user profiles and see how many have an account on [so], [su], [sf], [programmers.se], or one of the other tech-related sites.

Comment: Curious - why do you want to know?

Comment: just curiosity really.  This q can be closed if it's out of scope

Comment: How do you want this answered? Presumably people only know about themselves.

Comment: This q was inspired by [this post](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11824/suggestions-for-kosher-iphone-apps) and some of the responses/comments.  As a programmer, I'm just wondering how much geek-lore will be picked up by the community.  The answer, seems like "quite a bit".

Comment: If you wanted to survey the subset of Yodeyans who come to meta, you could post two answers, "I'm in IT" and "I'm not in IT", and ask people to vote.  (You could do it with one, with up and down votes, but not everybody would be able to see the results.)

Comment: Similar: [Rabbonim on the site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1615)

Answer (score 3):

using [@Aarthi's metric](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1388/how-many-regular-users-here-work-in-it#comment3921_1388), I counted 12.5 people in the [top 36 (first page) active this quarter](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter) who are NOT members of a technical SE.  The .5 is one user who is only a part of Mi Yodea and LaTeX user group (which though technical, does not imply IT industry).

So a super-majority of highly active users are in IT.  It seems that higher ranking correlates with IT (there were more in the top 12 than in the next 12).  I wonder why this is.  Maybe more time in front of a computer or more google-fu?

Comment: Though this count doesn't account for a lot, since I (one of the people in the top 36) know almost nothing about code, etc., although I do have an account on Super User, because that was only to ask two questions. Maybe a better way to count would be how many people are on a technical SE with at least a certain amount of reputation or with an *answered* question

Comment: @ba It's not a perfect metric.  I'm technical but not on technical SE.  Many new programmers or students might be technical but haven't answered any qs....

Comment: That's true, but if you're measuring by the number of people in those SE sites, [membership shows nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=259385&sort=votes)