# Rabbonim on the site

Tags: discussion, users

How many number of users of this site are either "qualified" (i.e. have smicha, shimush, etc) Rabbonim or are actually "praciticing" Rabbonim (Rabbi of a Shul, Dayanim, Morei Horah, etc.)

(This was simply asked to get statistics. It came from the fact that I've noticed that either people on this site are Baruch HaShem extremely learned or have access to the Torah Software and applications (Otzer HaChacham, Bar Ilan, Hebrew Books, etc) and can search very well. Or perhaps a combination of the two. If someone is looking for "general" information on a topic and not a psak he's more likely to post a question here and find great answers then to ask a Rov who may or may not know and won't have the same mareh makomos. It's quite valuable. Thus I was curious how many people are in fact Rabbonim here.)

Comment: Similar idea: [How many regular users here work in IT?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1388/how-many-regular-users-here-work-in-it)

Comment: would it be wrong of me to answer the question volunteering personal information (which I am not overly protective of)?

Comment: @Dan Personal information about yourself? Doesn't seem to be a problem?

Comment: the fact that I did or did not get smicha doesn't seem like something particularly private if I am willing to share it.

Comment: This is actually a very interesting question / issue. Since the rep # is one method of determining what a person's realiability is or "reputation" what is its relationship with outside means of measuring qualification, e.g. semicha, a doctorate, etc?

Comment: @Dan One approach is to create a meta question asking all rabbis to upvote it anonymously, similar to the new ["Where do you live?"](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1635) question. This would probably not be too useful beyond those rabbis who frequent meta, though.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to have confirmed Rabanim?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4522)

Answer (score 11):

There are no numbers on this, nor are there ever likely to be. Personal information is not required of anyone on this site, and never will be. Most people choose not to offer very much.

There have been several Rabbis who used their real names etc., but actual numbers do not exist.

Comment: Related: [Anonymity on Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/91)